# Kotlin Compose Desktop, can I drag a file path from my application to a third-party application?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

If I create a Windows/Linux desktop application using Kotlin Compose Desktop, can I drag a file (i.e., the file path) from my application into another application? I could do it in C# (WinForms) relatively with the following two lines of code:

```
var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filePathStringArray);
myListViewControl.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

[image]

Comment: this is a pretty narrow question, you're more likely to get an answer in [kotlin slack](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up), **#compose-desktop** channel

Comment: I think dragging anything from the Compose app to other apps is still unsupported. v1.6.0 seems to have the API for it, but it isn't implemented for Desktop right now. Maybe by the time v1.6.0 final appears, it will be though.